# What exactly is the Management Key on a yubikey?

Tags: smartcard, yubikey

The yubico documentation mentions that a Management Key can be set manually, or it can be inferred in the SoC when setting a PIN for the first time.

What exactly is that management key and how does it play any role on the CCID flow? What are the consequences of a compromise of that key?